# Error when opening saved file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I created a method to open a saved file based on the name of the file passed from another class, but I'm not sure if I'm calling or passing the file correctly between classes.

In this class the file names are stored in a list, when a name is selected the file name is passed to the other class and my `OpenSavedFile` method is called.

These are the two methods below,can someone point me in the right direction with this or tell me where I'm going wrong with it?

Method that passes file name to LocationDetails class:

```
//selects saved note name based on slected index in list
        private void NotesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/LocationDetails.xaml?note={0}", e.AddedItems[0]), UriKind.Relative));

            LocationDetails myFile = new LocationDetails();
            myFile.OpenSavedFile();

        }
```

My method that is supposed to open the file based on the name passed from the other previous class,but when the first statement is executed it gives this error `System.AccessViolationException`:

```
public void OpenSavedFile()
        {
            //breaks when stepping into below statement `System.AccessViolationException`
            string filename = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["note"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                using (var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    this.NoteTextBox.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    this.FilenameTextBox.Text = filename; reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the stack trace after the class breaks:

```
>   CarFind.DLL!CarFind.LocationDetails.OpenSavedFileFromList() Line 25 C#
    CarFind.DLL!CarFind.LocationDetailsList.NotesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e) Line 38   C#
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(System.Collections.Generic.List<object> unselectedItems, System.Collections.Generic.List<object> selectedItems)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.MakeSingleSelection(int index)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.HandleItemSelection(System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem item, bool isMouseSelection)  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnListBoxItemClicked(System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem item)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnManipulationCompleted(System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnManipulationCompleted(System.Windows.Controls.Control ctrl, System.EventArgs e) Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName)    Unknown
```

Comment: And...where's the problem located? Can you post the output/stacktrace...etc?

Comment: Yes its located at the first line of the OpenSaveFile(),I set a breakpoint and stepped into and it causes this error: `System.AccessViolationException`

Comment: Also I added the stack trace.

Comment: Try to wait until the navigation is complete because the `QueryString["note"]` may not be set yet when you open the file. Put a break-point on `string filename = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["note"];` and make sure it is the one you selected.

Comment: I don't think you can access NavigationContext from where you are but do try to use Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>myFile.OpenSavedFoile()) and see if that work.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder could you give a code example of how to use this dispatcher? I'm new to these utilities..Also I'm guessing that the reason its breaking its calling this line before navigation is complete as Laith said..How could I reaarange this method to accomadate this?

Comment: @BrianJ, when you say "class" you mean View/Page, right?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Yes I mean viewpage,the locationdetails page is called from the main menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LocationDetailsList.xaml.cs, make it

```
//selects saved note name based on slected index in list
private void NotesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/LocationDetails.xaml?note={0}", e.AddedItems[0]), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In LocationDetails.xaml.cs, put:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(NavigationContext.QueryString == null)
    {
        //QueryString is null
    }
    else if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("note"))
    {
        _openSavedFile(NavigationContext.QueryString["note"]);
    }
    else
    {
        //QueryString does not contain a "note" parameter and QueryString is not null
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private _openSavedFile(string filename)
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store))
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        this.NoteTextBox.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        this.FilenameTextBox.Text = filename;
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Remove your old OpenSaveFile() method from LocationDetails.xaml.cs

Comment: problem is the LocationDetails class is being called firstly by a button click eventfrom the menu in the app main page. So if I use this solution, the onNavigatedTo() will be called with no query string as it hasn't yet got to the stage of adding a note.

Comment: The LocationDetails.xaml.cs is the page being navigated to from the LocationDetailsList.xaml.cs so the QueryString will contain a note parameter? Am I wrong?

Comment: What if the query string is null because it is the first time being navigated to? Can I use an if..else  Could you show an example in your above solution?

Comment: Added it to my solution, @BrianJ

Comment: That solved it, so the problem was that the query string was null when called in onNavigatedTo.Thanks for your help +1

Answer (score 1):

In the code-behind for `LocationDetails.xaml`, there will be a method you can override called `OnNavigatedTo(...)`. You should open your file there.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(...)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("note"))
    {
        LocationDetails myFile = new LocationDetails();
        myFile.OpenSavedFile();
    }
}
```

You navigation context will be populated with the query string you previously selected. Assuming you did everything else right :)

Comment: the LocationDetails class is being called firstly by a button click event in the app main page. So if I use this solution, the onNavigatedTo() will be called with no query string.

Comment: Then put an if-statement to check if it exists.

Comment: Also, if you're using `LocationDetails` in the main page, then the query string will never have a "note" value. Your navigation context will only apply the query string to the `LocationDetails.xaml` page.

Comment: I'm just calling the locationdetails page from main page, so user clicks add details it will open this page, the user will be brought back to locationdetails after they pick a file from the list in locationDetailsList..Also I would just add an else clause to the above? to break if no query string or how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your LocationDetails.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        OpenSavedFile();
    }
```